# Checking for null is not working for ajax json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, variables, null

I am getting data from ajax call like

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5bd00e99d2ccda119c0032da"},"AllotmentsDetails":null}]
```

I am comparing it for null value like

```
var allotmentDetailsArray = data[0]['AllotmentsDetails'];

if (allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0 || allotmentDetailsArray == null)
{
    ////
}
```

It is not going in if condition... Please help !!!

Comment: You can't check the `length` of a null. Null does not have `length` property. There's already an error in your console saying `Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

Comment: Perform the `null` check first, otherwise you'll get an error accessing `length` property of `null`

Comment: Try with `===` `if (allotmentDetailsArrayc === null)` & remove length check

Comment: did you tried `allotmentDetailsArray === null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check null first then check for length

```
if (allotmentDetailsArray == null || allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0)
{
      ////
}
```

Comment: why double equals?

Answer (score 3):

You have to check against `null` before trying to access the `object`, in your `if` block you are trying to call `.length` on a `null` object.

You can do it like this:

```
if (!allotmentDetailsArray || allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0)
{
    ////
}
```

Where `!allotmentDetailsArray` is a shortened expression for `allotmentDetailsArray == null` which checks that `allotmentDetailsArray` is `undefined` or `null`.

So here the second part of the `if` block is only checked when `allotmentDetailsArray` is not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check length of a null value. However you can check null value and array length with this code.

```
if (!allotmentDetailsArray) {
  // null check here. you cannot check array length here since it's a null value
} else {
  // if you want to check array length 
  if (allotmentDetailsArray.length === 0 ) {
    // check here
  }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check  null or not null. if its not null means then check length.

Please try it.

```js
//Ex:1
var data= [{"_id":{"$oid":"5bd00e99d2ccda119c0032da"},"AllotmentsDetails":null}];

var allotmentDetailsArray = data[0]['AllotmentsDetails'];

if (allotmentDetailsArray == null)
{
    alert(allotmentDetailsArray);
}
else if(allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0)
{
    alert(allotmentDetailsArray.length);
}
//or
if (allotmentDetailsArray == null ||allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0 )
{
alert(allotmentDetailsArray);
}

//Ex:2
var data= [{"_id":{"$oid":"5bd00e99d2ccda119c0032da"},"AllotmentsDetails":""}];

 allotmentDetailsArray = data[0]['AllotmentsDetails'];

if (allotmentDetailsArray == null)
{
    alert(allotmentDetailsArray);
}
else if(allotmentDetailsArray.length == 0)
{
    alert(allotmentDetailsArray.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the type:

```
var allotmentDetailsArray = data[0]['AllotmentsDetails'];

if (typeof allotmentDetailsArray !== "undefined")
{
  // Var is not null
}
```

Comment: This is flawed as `null` !== `undefined`.